# Working women in islam?

Tags: women

I just wanted to know if a women wishes to work as an officer or in some governmental office etc.,by maintaining her hijab and conduct then is she allowed .because may Allah forgive me but being an educated women, who have learnt to be independent and thinks that she to can contribute to society and her family is it fair that we need to still depend on the permission of men to work...... 
 The work which we do can be beneficial to women even if it's not just teaching or nursing ....

So please help me by sharing your views. I think when women are allowed to work then they should also be allowed to work in fields where she wishes and there are many places like politics, administration and even sports for that matter... and when Allah(swt) meant stay in your houses it was compared to the then condition of women .....and also they were many women during the prophet's(pbuh)who used to help him bring food and water during wars.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we recommend you check out the FAQ.  We would also like to recommend that you look around this site to get an idea on how it works, again we welcome you to this site :)

Comment: A very good question. Which so much restriction on women, for them to ask permission from mahram to go outside etc, it would be safe to say, there is not concept of working women in Islam. However that must change!

Answer (score 2):

Assalaam Alaikum,
Caliph Umar al Khattab had a lady to be the controlar of the market in Madinah. Her responsibility was to check Price and quality of the products in the market and to disallow monopoly trade. hope this answers your question. Allah knows best

Answer (score 2):

The Quran provides several examples of women being active role models in their societies and interacting with men, such as Abraham’s wife:

> **11:69** Our messengers came to Abraham with good news, they said,
> "Peace" He said, "Peace," and it was not long before he came back with
> a roasted calf.
>
> **11:70** But when he saw that their hands did not go towards it, he
> mistrusted them, and felt a fear of them. They said, "Have no fear, we
> have been sent to the people of Lot."
>
> **11:71** His wife was standing, so she laughed when We gave her good news
> of Isaac, and after Isaac, Jacob.

Muslim women in Madyan with one whom Moses married:

> **28:23** When he arrived at the watering hole of Midyan, he found a crowd
> of people watering. He noticed two women waiting on the side. He said,
> "What is holding you back." They said, "We cannot draw water until the
> shepherds finish, and our father is an old man."
>
> **28:24** So he drew water for them, then he turned to a shaded area, and
> he said, "My Lord, I am poor, lacking any provisions You may have sent
> down."
>
> **28:25** So one of the two women approached him, shyly, and said, "My
> father invites you to reward you for watering for us." So when he came
> to him, and told him his story, he said, "Do not fear, for you have
> been saved from the wicked people."
>
> **28:26** One of the two women said, "O my father, hire him. For the best
> to be hired is one who is strong and honest."
>
> **28:27** He said, "I wish you to marry one of my two daughters, on
> condition that you work for me through eight pilgrimage periods; if
> you complete them to ten, it will be voluntary on your part. I do not
> wish to make this matter too difficult for you. You will find me, God
> willing, of the righteous."
>
> **28:28** He said, "It is then an agreement between me and you. Whichever
> period I fulfill, you will not be averse to either one. God is
> entrusted over what we said."

The Queen of Sheba who later surrenders to the will of God (**27:34:40**), and Mary (**19:16-30; 3:42-43; 66:11-12**).

Muslim women were so outspoken that they could engage in debate with Muhammad!
The rights of women during the time of prophet Muhammad is reflected with all
its power in verse **58:1**, where a Muslim woman argues with Muhammad regarding
her husband. God does not reprimand that woman; to the contrary, God sides
with the grievances of the woman and criticizes the superstition. A critical study
of hadith and history books will reveal that even those books contain many hints
regarding the individual, social and political rights enjoyed by women during the
era of revelation and even decades afterwards. History books report that Aisha,
Muhammad's wife, in her old age became the leader and commander of a major
faction that participated in a civil war that took place thirty years after the departure
of Muhammad.

> **58:1** God has heard the woman who argues with you regarding her
> husband, and she complains to God. God hears the argument between you.
> God is Hearer, Seer.

Additionally, women pledged allegiance and voted for Muhammad’s leadership (60:12).

> **60:12** O you prophet, if the acknowledging women come to make
> allegiance to you that they will not set up anything beside God, nor
> steal, nor commit adultery, nor kill their born children, nor fabricate any falsehood, nor disobey you in any matter which is righteous, then you shall accept their allegiance, and ask God to forgive them. God is Forgiver, Compassionate.

SOURCE: [Reformist Translation](https://www.google.com/search?q=Reformist%20Translation)

Answer (score 1):

If she is truly independent, then she may work as she wills so long as the basic Islamic rules of modesty and behaviour are adhered to.  A woman is still, however, expected to be [dutiful to her husband](http://quran.com/4/34) and [kind to her parents](http://quran.com/4/36); regardless of whether working is *haram* (it's not), one still should refrain from doing so without their blessings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if women can work it is not bad to do work because ISLAM does clearly say that women has to just live in homes and do the domestic work or ISLAM does not say that the men can not help in domestic works so its our society which make limits that the women is to just stay in homes and the men can do the works which are outside the they can not help in domestic work is that any thing present in QURAN? no such thing is present in ISLAM its just our society which make all these limits although we all know that our HOLY PROPHET (PBUH) love to do work and HE (PBUH) always do his own work but the man of today just want to take all there things ready is our ISLAM says this? No but if women speak for their rights in front of men then they always put ISLAM between the women's dreams and wishes but in reality they did not know well about ISLAM.